# Java Final Variable Initialization

Tags: java

I get an error that says that the size variable might not have been initialized even though i have initialized it in the constructor. why doesn't this work ?=

```
public class Ore {

protected static final float size;
protected String name;
protected int itemID;
protected ArrayList<Mineral> minerals;

public Ore(float size, String name, int itemID){
       this.size = size;
       this.name = name;
       this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    public String getPrizeData(int itemNumber){
       String data = null;

       return data;
    }

    public float getPrice(){
        float price = 0;

        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

drop the `static` modifier from size... I'm pretty sure you don't want it there ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected static final float size;
```

Combination of `final` and `static` is considered **CONSTANT** in java and the *Compiler* replaces the constant name (*Here* `size`) everywhere in the code with its value during compilation so it's not allowed here to initialize it in `constructor` and generates compile time error.

---

So either go for the *vikingsteve's* solution or initialize it at the time of declaration.

Comment: I tried to write something like this and got horribly muddled. Thanks for a clear concise explanation, it's obvious to me now!

Comment: "the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code [...] during compilation" is simply not true. If you initialize it e.g. with the value from a static function the right hand side of the assignment is no longer a constant expression and can't be inlined by the compiler (JIT compilation may be a different story).

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a static field. As such it has to be initialized directly in the declaration or form a **static** initializer, i.e. like this:

```
public class Ore {

    protected static final float size;

    static{
        size = // add something here
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that static contexts are messy, hard to test and debug, and should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have things it *would* be possible to derive a class from `Ore` and implement a public static function in that derived class that refers to `size`. This is one way in which `size` could be accessed prior to initialisation and the compiler is correctly identifying that.

One fix would be to use a static initialiser block in `Ore` which initialises `size`, or set its value to a literal: `protected static final float size = /*ToDo - a literal here*/;`